Migrating a mysql 5.6 database to mysql 8, "1115, Uknown character set: 'utf8mb3'"
On Heroku/ClearDB I have a mysql 5.6 database that works fine.
I'm trying to migrate this database over to a mysql 8 database.
After making a backup file of my mysql5.6 database, I loaded it into my mysql8 database.  I was able to do that.  However whenever I use my app to access the database I get this error:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1115, "Unknown character set: 'utf8mb3'")
I dropped all my tables and went into my backup file and replaced every instance of utf8 to utf8mb4
I still get the same error.
I have run this command:
ALTER DATABASE [database name] CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
However I get the same error.  I don't know where else I can get rid of utf8 or utf8mb3.  Is there a command I have to run to make this work?
when I run this command (after trying all of the above):
SHOW variables like 'char%';
I get this
# Variable_name, Value
'character_set_client', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_database', 'utf8mb3'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_server', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_system', 'utf8mb3'
'character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/percona-xtradb-cluster/charsets/'

when I run
show variables like 'collation%';
I get:
# Variable_name, Value
'collation_connection', 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
'collation_database', 'utf8mb3_general_ci'
'collation_server', 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

How do I get this to work on mysql8?  I think I have to get all of those variables to show utf8mb4 but don't know how

It's possible you need to upgrade the client. When they changed utf8 to utf8mb3, it broke some client connectors that didn't know about this new name for the respective charset. I know there was an active bug for the .NET connector, but this is the first time I've heard Python is affected (I assume you are using Python because you tagged your question 'flask').

@BillKarwin yes I am using Python!  I just ran mysql -V on my machine and it says it is version 8.0.36, so it is new.  Did you mean something else?

I mean the Python connector. If the compatibility issue is like it was reported for .NET, the problem is that the connector is linked to a version of the MySQL client lib that does not recognize the new charset new.

see: Character set 'utf8' unsupported in python mysql connector
